# Download a file using P2P to a remote server

Tags: p2p, bittorrent, torrent, libtorrent

I would like to know if it's possible, using libtorrent-rasterbar, to download a torrent and save it to a remote location (a remote server for instance) instead of saving it to local disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the features list mentions that the storage API [is customizable](http://www.libtorrent.org/features.html#customizable-file-storage).
The [storage interface](http://www.libtorrent.org/reference-Custom_Storage.html#storage_interface) makes no reference to disk-specific things, thus there is nothing that excludes remote storage.